# Can I annotate a member inherited from a superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

If I have a class such as:

```
class Person {
  private String name;
  ...constructor, getters, setters, equals, hashcode, tostring...
}
```

Can I subclass and apply annotations to the name field in the subclass, for example to apply persistence annotations, without re-implementing the rest of the class?

```
@Entity
class Employee extends Person {
    @Column(...)
    private String name;
}
```

Comment: You could override the getter/setter and put the `@Column` there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you can't.

What you are proposing is field *shadowing* - you can't override a field.

The field `name` in the subclass has nothing whatsoever to do with the field `name` in the super class, other than it shares the same name of "name" and thus to distinguish the field in the super class, one must refer to it as `super.name` in the subclass.

Doing this is generally considered a "bug" (or a potential bug anyway), and best practices are to not shadow fields, because it is so easy to refer to the wrong field without knowing it.

Comment: I think you missed the point. The question is about annotating members that are defined in a superclass, not about shadowing them.

Comment: @david The question is about wishing to add annotations to superclass fields by “overriding” the field, which you cannot do; OP has *shadowed* the superclass field, which has no effect of the superclass field. You cannot annotate members of the superclass from a subclass.

Answer (score 18):

That wont work since the fields in super class will not be affected, but you  can try this

```
@Entity
class Employee extends Person {
  @Column(name="xxx")
  @Override
  public void setName(String name) {
     super.setName(name);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Also works, and I'd say was clearer, for overridden (`@Override`) getter methods.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but I think overriding the getter method is a solid approach.

This can be a superclass for all tables which has an id field. If you serialize this object into JSON the id will always appear.

```
@MappedSuperclass
class ModelEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(
        name      = "id",
        updatable = false,
        nullable  = false
    )
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id
}
```

But let's say you have the following objects (tables) `Person` and `Occupation` where `Person` has a one to many relationship with `Occupation`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "occupation")
Occupation extends ModelEntity {

    @Column
    String company

    @Column 
    String position
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
Person extends ModelEntity {

    @Column
    String name

    @OneToMany
    Occupation occupation
}
```

Provided that id is present in all of the classes that extend `ModelEntity` if you were to serialize a `Person` object, you would get something like:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Jordan",

    "occupation" : {
        "id" : 1,
        "company" : "WalMart",
        "position" : "Engineer"
    }

}
```

If you did not want the id to show up in the `Occupation` object, but you did want it to show up in the `Person` object, you can implement a `getId()` method at the `Occupation` class level, and apply desired annotations:

```
@Transient
public Long getId() {

    return id;   
}
```

Now your JSON would appear as follows: even though they both have an id column in the actual database:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Jordan",

    "occupation" : {
        "company" : "WalMart",
        "position" : "Engineer"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No - you will get two different fields. The annotated name field in `Employee` will be hiding the name field in the `Person` class. `Person.name` will not be annotated.