# Is it possible to index superclass' public fields from a child class, using Spring Data and MongoDB's indexing feature?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I'm trying to simplify domain and model maintenance from my application, and basically I want to have a set of common classes for both server and client sides.

Let's say we have a simple class that we want to use both in server and client sides:

```
public class Tag {
    public String name;
}
```

And then a child class from it, that only resides in the server side, where I want to make sure that the field `name` is indexed @MongoDB level:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class TagServer extends Tag {
    @Indexed(this.name) // Something like this?
    @Indexed(all fields from super class?) // Or even better something like this?
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this with annotations? Maybe there is another good approach for it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer is not quite true. As pointed out by @kapitanpattimura, @Indexed can only be used directly on fields.

The workaround which I used is [@CompoundIndex](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/CompoundIndex.html). So in your case, it should be something like this:

```
@Document
@CompoundIndex(name = "name_idx", def = "{'name': 1}")
public class TagServer extends Tag {
}
```

I've used this all the time and verified that the outcome is identical as if [@Indexed](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/Indexed.html) was applied to name field in the super class.

[@CompoundIndexes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/index/CompoundIndexes.html) can be used to define multiple indexes (as you wished to index all other fields).

Please note that as its name suggests, @CompoundIndex accepts multiple fields per index. So mix and match how it fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

**Please see coolersport's answer as it is better than this one.**

---

You cannot annotate the super class' field.  If Spring's annotations can be placed on the accessor methods instead of the fields (e.g. like JAX-B or Hibernate annotations) then you can however override the super classes' getter methods for those fields and annotate those getter methods (as described in the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319266/can-i-annotate-a-member-inherited-from-a-superclass)).

If not then I think you're out of luck.  One possibility is to automatically generate the client side code based on the server side code (using an annotation to indicate which fields should be kept) but that requires extra work to setup the code generation.  We've done this on some projects I've worked on because we've had to supply client libraries in multiple languages.

Comment: Thanks @Pace for the answer. Unfortunately '@Indexed' annotation cannot be applied to a method so even if the getter is overridden still cannot be added to the document.